# how can I add phone "tel" link in shortcode

Tags: shortcode

Im challanged with adding a "tel" link in a shortcode.  I have tried several ways and I have not succeeded.
Here is a sample of the current code:

```
[vc_custom_heading text="(123) 456-7890" font_container="tag:p|font_size:22px|text_align:left|color:#326496|line_height:26px" use_theme_fonts="yes" font_weight="600" link="url:tel:1234567890|title:Phone Number" el_class="ms-0 ms-lg-4 mr-md-0 ps-3 ps-md-1 mb-0 d-none d-md-block"]
```

Thank You,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  See code below.

```
[porto_info_box pos="top" icon_type="porto" read_more="box" icon_size="55" icon_border_radius="500" title="Phone Number" subtitle="(123) 456-7890" title_font_style="700" subtitle_font_style="300" icon_porto="porto-icon-tablet" icon_color="#3296c8" title_font_size="1.5em" title_font_color="#ffffff" subtitle_font_size="1.2em" subtitle_font_color="rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" icon_margin_bottom="16px" title_margin_bottom="1px" sub_title_margin_bottom="0px" el_class="p-b-lg mb-5" link="url:tel%3A1234567890"]
```